# if statement either says invalid syntax or unexpected indent, my first time using python (very simple code)

Tags: if-statement

```
print ("Hey there Aga!")
print  (" ")
begin = input("would you like to begin?: ")
if begin == "yes":
print ("very well then, ill give you an easy question to find the password for the first folder..")
print (" ")
print ("A) Hajiko")
print ("B) Hajika")
print ("C) Hajima")
q1 = input ("what was the noise my phone made when we lost it?")
if q1 == 1
print ("yeah boy")
```

im so confused what do i do lmao, literally all that its saying is about the syntax or the indent??

Comment: Learn the basics of the syntaxis. Everything that goes in the 'true' if-statement should be indented. Also, the last if has a missing ":" at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indentation is used to define scope, much like `{}` in C.  You'll need to indent everything you want to be included in each of your `if`s like so:

```
print ("Hey there Aga!")
print  (" ")
begin = input("would you like to begin?: ")
if begin == "yes":
  print ("very well then, ill give you an easy question to find the password for the first folder..")
  print (" ")
  print ("A) Hajiko")
  print ("B) Hajika")
  print ("C) Hajima")
  q1 = input ("what was the noise my phone made when we lost it?")
  if q1 == 1:
    print ("yeah boy")
```

Note:  the second `if` is included inside the first, so its contents must be indented another level.